# How do I make a switchable twitter feed?

Tags: php, html, twitter

I tried to make a PHP script for it, but i can't get past the "wiget id"(marked by ???).

Using the feed from twitter, I added variables to the links, but my small php knowledge limits me. 
Its not much, but this is what i cam up with:

```
<?php
$feed = $_POST['Feed'];
    echo "<FORM NAME =\"Feed\" METHOD =\"POST\" action=\"\">
              <INPUT name=\"Feed\" TYPE = \"TEXT\" VALUE =\"BillGates\">
              <INPUT TYPE =\"Submit\" VALUE =\"OK\">
        </FORM>";
    echo "<button formaction=\"Feed\">Reload @" . $feed ."</button><br \>";
    echo "<a class=\"twitter-timeline\" data-dnt=true href=\"https://twitter.com/" . $feed . "\" data-widget-id=\"???????????????\">Tweets by @" . $feed . "</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=\"//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,\"script\",\"twitter-wjs\");</script>";
    ?>
```